# Create separate object of unique keys from array of object, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, arraylist

How can we make separate objects of unique keys?
Below is the sample array:

```
var arr = [
  {"name": "john"},
  {"email": "john@gmail.com"},
  {"phone": "2222222"},
  {"name": "jack"},
  {"email":"jack@gmail.com"},
  {"phone":"2222222333"}
]
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        {"name" :"john"},
        {"email": "john@gmail.com"},
        {"phone": "2222222"}
    }, 
    {
        {"name": "jack"},
        {"email": "jack@gmail.com"},
        {"phone": "2222222333"}
    }
]
```

Comment: Request output is invalid.

Comment: Your desired output does not make sense

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are looking for that ?

```js
const data = 
  [ { name  : 'john'           } 
  , { email : 'john@gmail.com' } 
  , { phone : '2222222'        } 
  , { name  : 'jack'           } 
  , { email : 'jack@gmail.com' } 
  , { phone : '2222222333'     } 
  ] 
const result = data.reduce((w,row,i) =>
  {
  let [key,val] = Object.entries(row)[0]
    
  if (!i || w.el.hasOwnProperty(key) ) 
    {
    w.el = { [key]: val }
    w.res.push(w.el) 
    } 
  else
    w.el[key] = val

  return w 
  }, { res:[], el:null } ).res
  
console.log( result )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

Comment: how about `const result = data.reduce(...).res;` instead of that construct with `next` and conditional returns.

Comment: @Thomas you're right, and then it makes less calculations on execution times, thanks  :)